# How to disconnect from a particular database in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I use this snippet to connect to another db

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection....
```

but I don't know how to delete this connection after it is not needed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can call `remove_connection`

```
old_connection = ActiveRecord::Base.remove_connection
```

If you have done something like the following *(where there is an assignment)*

```
new_connection = ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(...)
```

This can be passed on to `remove_connection`

```
old_connection = ActiveRecord::Base.remove_connection(new_connection)
```

You can find it in [the source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/11c697383e6fea7834ee1a8ba2815ff0da20f0fe/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb#L87-L89).

Comment: just curios about connection and connection pool. Can't we remove the connection like `new_connection.disconnect!` or `ActiveRecord::Base.clear_active_connections!`

Comment: @Dharshan `ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.active_connection?.try(:disconnect!)` seems to be working

Answer (score 3):

```
 your_connection = ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(...)

 ActiveRecord::Base.remove_connection(your_connection)
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is indeed `remove_connection( klass=self)`.  However, `establish_connection(...)` returns the connection, not the base class, so the code instead should be:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(...)
ActiveRecord::Base.remove_connection( ActiveRecord::Base)
```

To differentiate different connections (useful for handling multiple databases, for example), you can create a subclass to make it easier. This will only disconnect the associated connection, and even with repeated calls, none belonging to the parent class.

For example:

```
class MyDatabase::Base < ActiveRecord::Base
  def example_connection_and_disconnection
    MyDatabase::Base.establish_connection(...)
    MyDatabase::Base.remove_connection( MyDatabase::Base)
  end
end
```

Hope this helps others out there. :-)